# Select2 Closes Modal on Clicking it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-select2

I have 7 SELECT2 Elements on my Modal, at first, I was unable to search on the select2 elements. I then added this line of code when I'm about to show the Modal

> $('#my-select').select2({
> dropdownParent: $('#my-modal')  }),

and I was able to search on the select elements. Now the problem is sometimes when I click on one of the options in select2, it automatically closes the Modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced this same problem, but as you can find in the original documentation. you can override Bootstrap's behavior by placing

```
$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function() {};
```

Before initialize any of the modals.

check https://select2.org/troubleshooting/common-problems for further explanation

Answer (score 2):

This works for me (Bootstrap 5)

```
$('#my-select').select2({
    dropdownParent: $('#my-select').closest('div')
});
```